# Styles will be applied for all elements though class or id

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. I have some a, p, etc tags in html. Some of them have classes or ids. Everything was ok, but I have made a footer, that also contain some p,a, h tags,etc... If I give a style for elements in footer, all same elements in html take the styles. I have tried make id+class, or footer #footer .footer p, h4... I have made a footer as a div, nothing works. The styles will be applied for all of elements.
here is my code

```
 <header>

    <p>Ievgen</p>
    <nav>
        <a name="home"></a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home"class='coollink'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aboutme" class="coollink" >About me</a></li>
        <li><a href="work.html" class="coollink" target="_self">Professional experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="publications.html" class="coollink">Publications</a></li>
        <li><a href="art.html" class="coollink" target="_blank">Art</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="coollink">Code</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="coollink">Contact</a></li>
</nav>
</ul>
</header>

<div class="footer">
        <hr>
        <h4>Write me</h4>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href=""></a>
        <a href=""></a>
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2018. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </div>



header{
    width: 80%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:  rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 1;

}
header p {
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav{
    float:  right;


}
 nav ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 70px;
    padding-top: 17px;
}
nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


.footer{
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('../images/footer.jpg');
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;

}

.footer h4, a, p{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using `<footer>` tag instead of `<div>` tag with footer class.

Comment: And then add styles like `footer {...} `

Answer (score 1):

In your last part of CSS, you just wrote it wrong. Try:

```
.footer h4, .footer a, .footer p {
 margin: 0;
}
```

I should also point out that you could just not use `<div class="footer">` and just use `<footer>` instead. That would be better HTML5.

Comment: Thanks... But it doesn't work... I find out, that my html do not accept any classes or id. Is it possible  occasionally to turn them off in Sublime text?

Comment: So it is working only if I do for each tag a separate line and a footer

Answer (score 0):

At the base of the problem here is adding styles to HTML tags. When you add styles to the **tag** it will override any styles applied through **classes**.

So, if you **WANT** styles to apply to every instance of the HTML element, apply styles to the tag.

HTML:

```
<p>
  {* header contents... *}
</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
  {* any styles here will apply to ALL <p> tags
}
```

If you **DON'T** want styles to apply to every instance, classes should be your go-to.

HTML:

```
<p class="paragraph">
  {* some styled text... *}
</p>

<p>
  {* some unstyled text... *}
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.paragraph {
  {* styles applied here will only apply to <p> tag with "paragraph" class *}
}
```

Comment: Tkanks. I know it... Everything was good before. But this time even if I have a class or id, or both it won't apply a style to tag with this class. It is applied to all same tags